# Unbreak specific text lines

Tags: bash

I have a subtitle file. I want unbreak all subtitles.
An example:

```
1
00:02:08,315 --> 00:02:10,786
Hello Jim.
How are you?

2
00:02:10,869 --> 00:02:13,192
I'm well.
And you?
```

I want convert to:

```
1
00:02:08,315 --> 00:02:10,786
Hello Jim. How are you?

2
00:02:10,869 --> 00:02:13,192
I'm well. And you?
```

The subtitle numbers and timecodes should not be unbreak.
How can this be done with sed?

Comment: What is criteria of joining lines? Is it every 3rd and 4th line?

Comment: Some subtiles have only one line. That's my problem. Other subtitles have two lines. My Question: How unbreak all subtitles to one line?

Comment: You need to clarify how to identify subtitles in your input file?

Comment: Once again: The subtitle file contains subtitles with two or one spoken lines. The file is in the subrip format. I want convert all spoken lines into a single line after each timecodes. See the above example. I need a sed command that don't touch all subtitle number (1, 2, 3 etc) and the timecodes but only spoken text lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = ""; FS = "\n" }
     NR > 1 { print "" }
     { print $1; print $2;
       for (i = 3; i < NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i;
       print $NF;
     }' your_file.txt
```

Output:

```
1
00:02:08,315 --> 00:02:10,786
Hello Jim. How are you?

2
00:02:10,869 --> 00:02:13,192
I'm well. And you?
```

Comment: Sorry, this awk script does not work. You can test with a subtitle file from www.podnapisi.net. The awk script works only with the above example.

Comment: @user2874781 You should update your post with that. What subtitle for example? Can you give a specific link?

Comment: @user2874781 Of course the various answer you obtained didn't work: according to the link you give now, subtitles contains HTML-like tags that are **not** in the example given in the question... Is there some other requirement you didn't mention?

Comment: @user2874781 The file is not in UNIX format. Convert it first with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's|\r||' file.srt`.

Comment: Thank you, konsolebox. Your script works! I used your sed command.

Answer (score 0):

This little `awk` script will do the job. It is a little bit more complex than required, but can serve as a base for more advanced processing. Maybe...

```
awk 'BEGIN                     { state = "copy" }
     (state == "copy")         { print }
     /-->/                     { state = "text"; next }
     /.+/ && (state == "text") { printf("%s ",$0); next }
     /^$/                      { printf("\n\n"); state = "copy"; next }
     END                       { printf("\n") }
    ' < sub.txt
```

Given your input file, this produce:

```
1
00:02:08,315 --> 00:02:10,786
Hello Jim. How are you? 

2
00:02:10,869 --> 00:02:13,192
I'm well. And you?
```

---

**EDIT:**
After looking at the sample file you give as a comment to an other answer, I can only *guess* you want to merge consecutive `<i>...</i>` lines. So this simple Perl trick is enough:

```
sh$ unzip 56939b22f5174a770a79f6b0b0cf7caaee1c9dfb.zip
Archive:  56939b22f5174a770a79f6b0b0cf7caaee1c9dfb.zip
inflating: Red.Planet.2000.1080p.REPACK.BluRay.x264-7SinS.srt  

sh$ perl -0pe 's|</i>\r\n<i>| |m' < Red.Planet.2000.1080p.REPACK.BluRay.x264-7SinS.srt

1
00:00:35,661 --> 00:00:40,792
<i>By the year 2000, we had begun to overpopulate, pollute and poison our planet...</i>

2
00:00:41,208 --> 00:00:43,176
<i>...faster than we could clean it up.</i>

3
00:00:43,377 --> 00:00:48,053
<i>We ignored the problem for as long as we could but we were kidding ourselves.</i>
```

Comment: Sorry, this awk script does not work. You can test with a subtitle file from www.podnapisi.net. The awk script works only with the above example.

Comment: @user2874781 I'm definitively _not_ sure what you are looking for exactly, but from what I can guess, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, why you use 'm' and 's' modifier with your s/// expression, they are pointless at this context. Also in that file, some lines do not have <i /> tags, so your solution will be broken.. it's easiest to just remove trailing \r and try my solution, haha!

Comment: @lihao Thank you for pointing out the "stupid flags mistake". I obviously don't understand the "requirements" here. If it's only a matters of joining lines my first attempt using `awk` seems doing that -- over-engineered maybe, but definitively working. But, according to OP it is not...

Answer (score 0):

If all your sub-title blocks are separated by empty lines and you want to keep the first two line of each block and merge the rest with space. then you can probably use Perl:

```
perl -F'\n' -aln00e 'print "$F[0]\n$F[1]\n", (join" ",@F[2..$#F]), "\n"' myfile.txt
```

however this will be broken if there are empty lines within spoken lines. but I guess you won't care removing empty lines containing in the spoken lines. if so, just take a pre-processing step:

```
perl -lp0777e 's/\n\n+(?!\d+\n\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d\s*-->)/\n/g' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in the [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) language:

```
@(repeat)
@num
@fromtime --> @totime
@(collect)
@line
@(until)

@(end)
@(output)
@num
@fromtime --> @totime
@(rep)@line @(last)@line@(end)
@(end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr unbreak.txr sub.srt 
1
00:02:08,315 --> 00:02:10,786
Hello Jim. How are you?
2
00:02:10,869 --> 00:02:13,192
I'm well. And you?
```

The desired output is achieved easily, even though we have precisely extracted more features of the SRT file than we have to get the job done. We can easily bend the code into doing more complicated transformations.

Answer (score 0):

This command line works too:

```
cat red.srt | tr '\012' '\040' | sed 's/[0-9]\+ ..:..:..,... --> ..:..:..,.../\n\0\n/g' | sed 's/^[0-9]\+ /\n\0\n/g' | sed 's/^ *//g; s/ \+/ /g; s/ *$//g' | sed '1,2d' > final.srt
```

I know, this solution is not elegant, but it works perfectly for me.